# JavaScript inheritance with working code assistant and outlines?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, ide

I know a plenty of different approaches to JavaScript inheritance. I think one of the most important factors is whether code assistant and outline still works with the inheritance model.

For example, in ExtJS inheritance involves:

```
MyApp.SuperWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
    constructor: function() {
        this.doSomething();
        MyApp.SuperWindow.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    doSomething: function() {
    }
});
```

Our SuperWindow extends Ext's Window component with additional functionality of doing something. While this inheritance works, you lose code assistant and the outline in all IDEs I know (Eclipse, Netbeans, Aptana, NuSphere among others).

You could, however, do something like:

```
MyApp.SuperWindow = {
    constructor: function() {
        this.doSomething();
        MyApp.SuperWindow.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    doSomething: function() {
    }
});

MyApp.SuperWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, MyApp.SuperWindow);
```

But that just looks horrible. You need to type `MyApp.SuperWindow` thrice (not including the parent constructor call that you could write with `this`).

How would you go about inheritance in JavaScript while maintaining code assistants and outlines?

I would like to retain the concept of a parent/super with the inheritance model. Since the typical inheritance involves placing a copy of an object into one's prototype only, you get no such things as supers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite a fan of John Resig's [Simple Javascript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/), which is quite clean in syntax, e.g.:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(forename, surname)
  {
    this.Forename = forename;
    this.Surname = surname;
  }
});

var Employee = Person.extend({
  init: function(forename, surname, role)
  {
    this._super(forename, surname);
    this.Role = role;
  }
});

var employee = new Employee("Matthew", "Abbott", "Developer");
console.log(employee.Forename + " " + employee.Surname + " is a " + employee.Role);

console.log(employee instanceof Class);
console.log(employee instanceof Person);
console.log(employee instanceof Employee);
```